# Как вставить ответ после Ajax запроса

Tags: php, ajax, json

Не понимаю как вставить полученный ответ от сервера. Сам запрос мне удается успешно отправить и проголосовать, а вот количество голосов, возвращаемое сервером, не могу вывести. К сожалению, с jQuery знаком 2 недели.

HTML и jQuery

```
    <!-- кнопка записывает +1 в пользу контента -->
    <button class="vote"><img src="images/vote.png" alt=""></button>

   <script>
            $(function()
            {
                var requestData = {
                    vote: "89" // это ID контента за который отдают голос
                }

                $(".vote").click(function(e)
                {
                    $.get("pic.php?vote", requestData, function(data)
                    {
                        processServerResponse(data);
                    }, "json");
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });

            function processServerResponse(data)
            { // здесь работа с полученным ответом
             ...
    </script>
```

PHP (ответ)

```
...
        $query = "
                  SELECT
                        vote
                  FROM
                        files
                  WHERE
                        id = " . $_GET['vote'];
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
        {
            if ($row = $result->fetch_row())
            {
                //header('Content-Type: application/json');
                $data = ['votes' => $row[0]];
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit;
            }
...
```

На странице

```
    <!--
        это изначальный показатель, который требуется заменить на новый
        после отправки Ajax запроса
    -->
    Голосов: <span class="file-data">'.$row[1].'</span>
```

Comment: Замените `$_GET['vote']` на `(int)$_GET['vote']`, а то дыра у вас вида "sql-injection" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: @Visman благодарю, я убрал проверку чтобы сократить код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подставить значение в текст таким образом:

```
$('span.file-data').text(data.votes);
```

Comment: Его следует вложить внутрь  `function processServerResponse(data) {` ?

Comment: Да, в функцию обработки ответа

Comment: При GET запросе возвращается {"votes":"239"} , но при Ajax цифры не обновляются, поправьте меня, пожалуйста, http://jsfiddle.net/6uedb5pn/

Comment: Используйте data.votes. Получается так: `$('span.file-data').text(data.votes);` Должно работать

Comment: Plikard, не хочет. Та часть, которая отвечает за отправку запроса, срабатывает на 100%, так как после обновления страницы в браузере цифры меняются. Но выводить обновление в фоновом режиме не хочет.

Comment: data возвращает что-нибудь вообще? Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: JS: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1:0
Метод getPreventDefault() является устаревшим. Для его замены используйте метод defaultPrevented. jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:0        это все ...

Comment: Мало данных что бы понять что именно у вас не работает. Попробуйте вывести в консоль содержимое data.votes `console.log('data.votes');`